# Plugin Settings Wordpress 3.8.1 Running on Google App-engine SDK

Tags: php, python, mysql, wordpress, google-app-engine

Today I have installed MySQL, Python 2.7, Google App Engine SDK and Wordpress on the App Engine. Following this Google Documentation:       https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/wordpress

and this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4_VPdgeSaNY

Logging into wordpress as administrator I proceed to download UpdraftPlus - Backup/Restore.

When installed and clicking on settings I get a error message: `You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.`

Wordpress SEO by Yoast when clicked on also says `Fatal error: Call to a member function admin_header() on a non-object in C:\Empty\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\wordpress-seo\admin\pages\dashboard.php on line 104`.

The final thing I have noticed wrong is that I can create pages but not save them. Any suggestions on fixing this would be helpful. I would completely re-install if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using this instead of the article? It's much more up to date.

http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project/

The ZIPs there include the latest WordPress and WordPress Plugin for App Engine, and you'll want to be sure to use the latest App Engine SDK.

Comment: It worked like a charm, I did have to delete everything and start over but it was definitely worth it.